# NativeScript : I have to develop an offline app for Android + iOS + Web app. Offline data will be stored in SQLite DB

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Using native script, it is possible to access SQLite DB.  But is it possible to use SQLite DB from NativeScript + Angular web app?

Answer (score 0):

Anthing you can do in NativeScript Core, you can also do with NativeScript Angular, so yes you can access a SQLite database with NativeScript Angular as all you need is access to the local file system to store the SQLite database.

On the other hand, you mentioned "web app" so not sure if you meant to ask, **"Can you access a SQLite database from a shared mobile/web app, using NativeScript Angular for the mobile app, and regular Angular for the web browser app?"** If that is what you meant, then no, you wouldn't be able to access a SQLite database from the web app becuase SQLite databases are stored locally as a regular file, so there would be no way for an Angular web app in a web browser to access the same SQLite database file as a mobile app.  For this situtation, you would need a traditional database server setup like [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org), or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org), hosted on an external server, where both the mobile app, and the web browser app can access that same database over a network connection. You could easily have the Angular web app, and the database cluster, hosted from the same server.

I personally use a PostgreSQL database server with a shared NativeScript Angular mobile app/Angular web app in production and it works really well. It is really nice to be able to share a lot of the Angular code (mostly core services) between the mobile and web app.